# Como colocar um botão que execute uma ação AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: java, android

Tenho esse método em que exibe um mensagem.

```
public void mensagenExebir(String titulo, String texto){

         AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
         mensagem.setTitle(titulo);
         mensagem.setMessage(texto);
         mensagem.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
         mensagem.show();
     }
```

Tem como colocar outro botão para executar um comando?

Comment: Como assim colocar outro botão? Explique melhor o que quer fazer com este código.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe já tem um botão  que é `mensagem.setNeutralButton("OK", null);` gostaria de criar mais um que execute um comando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta adicionar usando o método [`setPositiveButton()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton(int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)):

```
public void mensagenExebir(String titulo, String texto){

         AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
         mensagem.setTitle(titulo);
         mensagem.setMessage(texto);
         mensagem.setNeutralButton("Cancelar", null);
         mensagem.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // ação a ser executada ao clicar no botão
           }
       });
         mensagem.show();
     }
```

> É recomendável que, para toda `string` de interface(como a legenda dos
>   botões e labels), você crie um `resource` no arquivo `strings.xml`.
>   Desta forma, facilita a manutenção e também a internacionalização do
>   seu aplicativo.

**Referência:**

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 4):

Até onde sei usando `AlertDialog.Builder` so da pra colocar até 3 botoes...
botao "POSITIVE" (setPositiveButton), botão neutro (setNeutralButton), e o "NEGATIVE" (setNegativeButton), mas se quiser mais coisas tipo um CheckBox ou uma barra de progresso use o objeto `Dialog`

**Exemplo de um dialog costumizado:**

```
public void showDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(androidialog.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog); // seu layout
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    Button cancelar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.idialog.cancelar);
    Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.idialog.ok);

    cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss(); // fecha o dialog
        }
    });
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             dialog.dismiss(); // fecha o dialog
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    }
```